# Matching only twice

Tags: perl

I want to match a word for exactly two times.The output should not display all occurrences of matching.How to do with perl?

```
open(a,"<file.txt");
open(c,">>output.txt");
while (my $line = <a>) {
        if($line =~ m/know{2}/) { 
          print $line;
        }
}
close(a);
close(c);
```

Example: 
If file.txt has following lines :

```
I know Perl.
I know English.
I know French.
I know Dutch.
```

The expected result should be :

```
I know Perl.
I know English.
```

Comment: `know{2}` will only match `knoww`. Maybe you wanted `\b(know)\b.*?\b(know)\b` ?

Comment: No.It should match first two occurrences of know(not in same line).Likewise,How to do it for n number of matching?

Comment: If they are different lines `if($line =~ m/know/) { ` should be enough.

Comment: If you are matching line-by-line, you will need to add additional program logic to keep track of how many words you have seen in your input. Your course material should have something on "hashes"

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be asking how to find the first two lines that contain `know`.

For that, you need to keep track of how many lines you've previously found.

```
my $count = 0;
while (<>) {
   if (/know/) {
      print;
      last if ++$count == 2;
   }
}
```

Comment: No friend, It should match exactly 2 times irrespective of lines.

Comment: I can't understand your comment, and your question remains unclear as ever. Please address these issues

Comment: you should maybe use the regex like this:
$line =~ m/^.*know.*know.*$/

Comment: @mirchev1977, That couldn't possibly result in the expected output.

Comment: could you post the content of the file "file.txt"?

Comment: @mirchev1977, That comment doesn't appear to relate to my answer.

Comment: @cherry, I see the update you've made to your question. My answer stands.

Comment: @ikegami,Your answer works for me but can you able to do anything with this syntax "a{n} = match exactly n times" ?

Comment: You want a line if it contains know, and if you've only printed one other line. That would not help you determine if a line contains `know`, and it would not help you determine if you've printed any earlier lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Perl one-liner

```
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN {$x=2} s/(know)/$x--;$kv{$_}=1/ge; if($x==0) { print keys %kv ; exit } ' cherry2.txt
I know Perl.
I know English.
$

$ cat cherry2.txt
I know Perl.
I know English.
I know French.
I know Dutch.
$
```